# Обособление оборота при наличии союза ХОТЯ

Tags: пунктуация

Правильно ли стоит запятая перед союзом ХОТЬ (и остальные запятые во втором предложении):

*Николас был поражен тем, что директор архива дает малознакомому человеку совет, да еще по такому интимному поводу, как стиль одежды. Немного подумав, магистр решил, что это(,) **хоть и бесцеремонно, но очень по-русски и, пожалуй, даже симпатично.***

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ (после полученного ответа)

Вариант с обособлением:

*Немного подумав, магистр решил, что Это, **хоть и бесцеремОнно**, но очень по-рУсски и, пожалуй, даже симпатИчно.*

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ (после второго полученного ответа)

**Я знаю (и знала) правило,** согласно которому применяются двойные союзы, полученная информация для меня не является новой.

Возможно, я не совсем четко сформулировала вопрос. Сейчас меня интересует вот что: **это ошибка редакторов или авторская (ненормативная) пунктуация,** которая тоже имеет право на существование. Хотя при одном условии: если в авторском оформлении есть какой-то **особый смысл**.

Может быть,кто-нибудь увидит этот смысл? Буду очень благодарна за информацию. Вот если бы Грамота.ру прокомментировала  именно это предложение, то  было бы интересно.

А истории про корректоров и редакторов из **разных** издательств, которые **перепечатывают** одну и ту же ошибку, любопытны, но вот насколько они правдивы, вот в чем  вопрос.

И еще раз напомню цитату из Розенталя: . Особенности русской пунктуации — в присущей ей многофункциональности знаков препинания и широкой их взаимозаменяемости, в своеобразии **индивидуально-авторского** использования знаков препинания, **в гибкости** пунктуационной системы, позволяющей выявлять не только смысловую сторону текста, но и стилистические его оттенки. Все это **исключает формальный подход** к соблюдению правил.

Answer (score 3):

> Если однородные члены [простого] предложения соединены двойными
>   союзами если не…то, **хотя…но** ... и т. п., то **запятая** ставится *только
>   перед второй* частью союза:  *Для Алевтины Васильевны хотя и привычна,
>   но тяжела была власть Ерофея Кузьмина* (Розенталь, справочник по
>   русскому языку. Пунктуация, § 14. Однородные члены предложения,
>   соединенные двойными или парными союзами, п.1.
>   http://modernlib.net/books/rozental_ditmar_elyashevich/spravochnik_po_russkomu_yaziku_punktuaciya/read_3/ )

Простое предложение с однородными членами здесь можно отделить от мыслей магистра в виде:

> Это хоть и бесцеремонно, но очень по-русски и, пожалуй, даже
>   симпатично.

Comment: Спасибо, так что же, здесь ошибка, которую все перепечатывают? Как-то не верится, что это так.  Мне же кажется, что автор хотел ОБОСОБИТЬ первую часть оборота, то есть выделить её по смыслу и интонационно. Я ведь могу прочитать предложение с обособлением, ничего в нем не меняя?

Comment: Видимо, автору оборот казался похожим на вводный, но из-за наличия "но" здесь не проходит и проверка на "изымаемость" двусторонне выделенного оборота (нарушается связность предложения).

Comment: Изымаемости, может,  и нет (да и почему она непременно должна быть),  но это совсем другой вариант по интонации и смыслу. Он имеет право на существование.Персонаж и раньше употреблял это выражение (очень по-русски), например: " ...как происходит в России  ритуал проверки паспортов. Неужто его принято начинать с рукопожатия? Это непривычно и, должно быть, не слишком гигиенично, если учесть, сколько пассажирских ладоней должен пожать офицер, но зато очень по-русски". Он как бы разделяет две темы: не очень правильно - но так по-русски.

Comment: Я тоже думаю, что запятая там лишняя.

Comment: @Sharon Я не вижу в последнем примере _двойных_ союзов; есть обособленные своими запятыми вводное выражение "должно быть" и предложение "если... сколько должен пожать офицер". Без этих вставленных конструкций остаётся следующее: _"Это непривычно и не слишком гигиенично, но зато очень по-русски."_ По грамматике исходный пример для меня выглядит так: _Эти киви хотя и твёрдые, но вкусные. Эти киви, хотя и твёрдые, очень вкусные._ Ради паузы после "это" автор мог многоточие поставить (как у Маяковского: "любая бумажка, но эту...").

Comment: Да я не про грамматику второго примера, а про смысл.  Автору важно подчеркнуть первый признак (бесцеремонно), поэтому у Акунина используется обособление. Если же считать, что это ошибка, неужели ее никто ее не видит? Другой вариант - это авторская (ненормативная) пунктуация. Просто не всё подходит под стандарт. В любом случае, спасибо за ваше мнение.

Comment: @Alex_ander плюсую за Ваш ответ. Всё по полкам разложили. Выражу надежду, что когда-нибудь здравый смысл и способность рассуждать будут иметь для масс большую убедительность, чем авторитет ленивых издательств.

Answer (score 0):

Александр дал абсолютно правильный ответ, вот что пишет Грамота.ру.:

Женщина все говорила и говорила о своих несчастьях, и, хотя слова ее были привычными для Сабурова, от них вдруг защемило сердце (Симонов). 
Женщина все говорила и говорила о своих несчастьях, и хотя слова ее были привычными для Сабурова, но от них вдруг защемило сердце.

Во втором предложении между союзом И и союзом ХОТЯ не ставится запятая, поскольку после уступительной придаточной части следует союз НО, фактически принимающий на себя функцию соединения первой и третьей частей сложного предложения. По этой причине во втором примере слова И ХОТЯ превращаются в единое союзное сочетание, не требующее разделения на письме при помощи запятой.